# Publicar algo no meu site e postar automaticamente no facebook

Tags: php, html, mysql, facebook, instagram-api

Boa tarde, tenho uma dúvida que to matutando pra entender. Vi em um sistema algo muito interessante que é quando a pessoa publica algum conteúdo no site dela, tem um botão que tu seleciona pra publicar também no facebook. É como o instagram que quando tu posta uma foto, tu tem a opção de postar automaticamente no facebook. Como funciona isso em php? Não tenho base nenhuma.

Comment: Obtenha o token do usuário e depois faça requisição para o Facebook como escrito em https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andei pesquisando e tudo isso funciona via API.
API é um conjunto de rotinas e padrões de programação para acesso a um aplicativo de software ou plataforma baseado na Web. A sigla API refere-se ao termo em inglês "Application Programming Interface" que significa em tradução para o português "Interface de Programação de Aplicativos".
Uma API é criada quando uma empresa de software tem a intenção de que outros criadores de software desenvolvam produtos associados ao seu serviço. Existem vários deles que disponibilizam seus códigos e instruções para serem usados em outros sites da maneira mais conveniente para seus usuários. O Google Maps é um dos grandes exemplos na área de APIs. Por meio de seu código original, muitos outros sites e aplicações utilizam os dados do Google Maps adaptando-o da melhor forma a fim de utilizar esse serviço.